# VLookup VBA function always return empty string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with my VBA function
`Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` always returns an empty string,
I try hardcode parameters and the result the same.

```
Public Function SeqVlookup(ByVal target As String, vrange As Range, vcol As Long)

    Dim WrdArray() As Variant  
    Dim text_string As Variant  


    text_string = target

    WrdArray() = Split(text_string,",")  

    Dim vlookupArray(0 To UBound(WrdArray)) As Variant  


    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 0 To UBound(WrdArray)  

      vlookupArray(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WrdArray(i), vrange, vcol, 0)


    Next i  

      SeqVlookup = Join(vlookupArray, ",")
      MsgBox Join(vlookupArray, ",") 

End Function
```

Command to init

```
   =SEQVLOOKUP(1,Sheet2.A:B,2)
```

Comment: I don't see how you can get as far as producing the wrong result with the line `Dim vlookupArray(0 To UBound(WrdArray)) As Variant`.

Comment: explanation please @SJR

Comment: Paste that code into the VBE, run it and tell me you don't get the message referred to here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185595/error-in-excel-vb-function-constant-expression-required

Comment: Do you get an error message when you remove `On Error Resume Next`?  The problem with that line of code is that the code could be doing a whole load of illegal stuff (emptying your bank account, robbing your neighbours, twocking your car) and you've told it to carry on regardless without mentioning it you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below seems to work.  Note that Split needs to populate a String array.
A possible reason the VLOOKUP didn't work is that the lookup keys are strings and possibly the values in the range were numeric?  The code below tries both.

```
Public Function SeqVlookup(ByVal target As String, vrange As Range, vcol As Long) As Variant

    Dim WrdArray() As String
    Dim vlookupArray() As Variant

    WrdArray = Split(target, ",")

    ReDim vlookupArray(LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray))

    Dim i As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)
        vlookupArray(i) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WrdArray(i), vrange, vcol, False)

        If IsEmpty(vlookupArray(i)) Then
            If IsNumeric(WrdArray(i)) Then
                vlookupArray(i) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(WrdArray(i)), vrange, vcol, False)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0

    SeqVlookup = Join(vlookupArray, ",")
    MsgBox Join(vlookupArray, ",")

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, now it's working

```
Option VBASupport 1

Public Function SeqVlookup(ByVal target As String, vSheet As String, vrange As String, vcol As Long) As Variant
Dim WrdArray() As String
   Dim vlookupArray() As Variant
   WrdArray = Split(target, ",")

   If UBound(WrdArray) = -1  Then 
        SeqVlookup = ""
   Else
       ReDim vlookupArray(LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray))
       Dim i As Long
       Dim thisRange  As String
       thisRange = vrange
       Dim thisSheet  As String
       thisSheet = vSheet
       On Error Resume Next
       For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)
            Dim thisVal  As Integer
            thisVal = WrdArray(i)
            vlookupArray(i) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(thisVal, Worksheets(thisSheet).Range(thisRange), vcol, False)
       Next i
       On Error GoTo 0
       SeqVlookup = Join(vlookupArray, ",")
    End If   
End Function
```

=SEQVLOOKUP(C2,"sheet2","A:B",2)